# Curve Fitting Methods

Tags: curves, interpolation

What kind of curve-fitting method would be best to find an equation (if there is one) for this curve?

[image]

Comment: It seems an rotated hyperbola, in Wolfram Mathematica 

`\[Theta] = \[Pi]/8; Graphics[{Line@Table[{Cos[\[Theta]] Cosh[t] - 0.5 Sin[\[Theta]] Sinh[t],Sin[\[Theta]] Cosh[t] + 0.5 Cos[\[Theta]] Sinh[t]}, {t, -3, 3, 0.01}]}]`

Comment: I though about that, but since the scales of the x and y axis are different from one another in the picture, wouldn't it be slightly off from a hyperbola?

Comment: I suppose the stretch in one direction would only affect the eccentricity of the hyperbola, but don't know for sure. Should have the original data to make some test, to better understand

Comment: Yes, I do have the actual numbers. Also, I guess I could take the coordinates to be (constant*y) and that would make the picture consistent.

Comment: Of course, you could always split the curve into two functions, then you can use pretty much any common curve fitting method you'd like for functions (with a boundary condition that they meet). This would be (imo) the easiest, but also most rudimentary.

Comment: You mean two functions for each "half" of the hyperbola?

Comment: Actually, the axis rotation seems to be satisfactory for finding an equation for the hyperbola in $(x', y')$ and then using that to find an $(x, y)$ equation, if that makes sense. But it seems difficult to then find a solution between $r$ and $\theta$. Do you think splitting it into two different functions would fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an hyperpola. The fitting if very good. See below the method used and the details of the calculus.

Only a small number of points were taken from your graph thanks to graphical scanning.

The calculus and drawing were done with MathCad.

The notations and the equation come from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html

[image]